# Equivalence test for non-normal distribution: how to determine equivalence bounds?

Tags: nonparametric, equivalence, tost

I am trying to conduct a Mann-Whitney equivalence test (as described in Wellek's book *Testing Statistical Hypotheses of Equivalence and Noninferiority*) with the following code in R:

```
mawi(alpha,m,n,eps1_,eps2_,x,y) 
         [alpha-    significance level;
         m- size of Sample 1;
         n- size of Sample 2;
         eps1_- absolute value of the left-hand limit of the hypothetical equivalence range for 
                π_+ - 1/2;
         eps2_- right-hand limit of the hypothetical equivalence range for π_+ - 1/2;
         x- row vector with the m observations making up Sample1 as components;
         y- row vector with the n observations making up Sample2 as components]
```

Where `eps1` and `eps2` represent the equivalence bounds I want to test for. The equivalence bounds need to be specified as the **absolute value** of the left-hand and right-hand limit of the hypothetical equivalence range for $\pi_{+} - 1/2$. However, I don't know how to determine this value.

In case I want to test for an equivalence bound corresponding to Cohen's $d=0.57$ (for two samples of $N = 25$; $\alpha = 0.5$) how do I compute `eps1` and `eps2`?

Comment: Welcome to CV, DOMINIKA SLUSNA. :)

Comment: It is bizarre to think of what "equivalence" means when performing a Mann-Whitney test. If the means are different because the distributions are skewed, then what is considered to be *the same* about the two distributions if you conclude they're "equivalent"?

Comment: @AdamO Bizarre or not, these tests appear in the biostats lit. :) If we recall that the positivist rank sum test can be expressed as $\text{H}_{0}^{+}\text{: }P(X\ge Y) = \frac{1}{2}$, then the general (symmetric) negativist rank sum null is $\text{H}_{0}^{-}\text{: }|P(X\ge Y)| \ge \frac{1}{2}+\varepsilon$, with the specific one-side nulls $\text{H}_{01}^{-}\text{: }P(X\ge Y) \ge \frac{1}{2}+\varepsilon$ and $\text{H}_{02}^{-}\text{: }P(X\ge Y) \leq \frac{1}{2}-\varepsilon$.

Answer (score 1):

**You *do not* compute `eps1` and `eps2` because these are researcher choices.**

Equivalence testing (both the lower powered Two One-Sided Tests, or TOST framework, and the uniformly most powerful, or UMP test framework professed by Wellek) rely on a notion of **equivalence threshold**, or the minimum effect size that you the researcher find to be **relevant** (possibly informed by regulatory guidelines, as is the case with the FDA some some applications of bioequivalence in the United States). Put another way, the researcher effectively states *a priori* "I do not care about effect sizes smaller the equivalence threshold." I do not know what your data are, but, for example, when studying whether a policy changes national incidence rates of, say, HIV a researcher *might* say *a priori* "I do not care about effect sizes smaller than $\pm$1 new case of HIV per 100,000 people per year."

Some equivalence thresholds are expressed symmetrically on an absolute or relative scale. Some are expressed asymmetrically. The values of `esp1` and `esp2` are non-negative values that express what **you** find to be the appropriate boundary between relevant and equivalent, and correspond to **your choices** for the values of $\varepsilon_1^{\prime}$ and $\varepsilon_2^{\prime}$ in expression 6.10 on page 126 of Wellek (Second ed.).

Comment: Thank you, Alexis, for such a quick reply! I didn’t expressed myself well: Yes, I know that the equivalence bounds are to be set by the researcher. In my case I decided to set them at Cohen’s d of .57 (which is an effect I can reliably detect with my sample size). However, I don’t think I can values for “esp1” and “esp2” as d = +/-.57, right? 
It needs to be an absolute value, no? So, say that I want to see whether two samples are equivalent in chronological age (in years) and a mean difference of d=.57 corresponds to 2.4 years. So I set “esp1” and “esp2” to be -2.4, 2,4, respectively?